# Check minutes from time.struct_time object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check on the `time.struct_time` object to see if I have the minutes which is `30` then do something.

When I try this:

```
one_hour_half = str(self.getControl(346).getLabel())
epg_time_3 = time.strptime(one_hour_half, '%I:%M%p')
program_stop_time = time.strptime(prog_stop_clock, '%I:%M%p')


if program_stop_time > epg_time_3:
   if int(current_time) >= 30 and int(current_time) >= 59:
       if epg_time_3 == '30':
          print "you are here, now let do something..."
```

Results for `epg_time_3`:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=17, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

It won't let me to get pass on the `if epg_time_3` statement. That is because I'm using `time.struct_time`, so I use the variable `one_hour_half` which is show the string as `5:30PM`. I want to know how I can use the time.struct_time object `epg_time_3` to see if I have the minutes `30`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `epg_time_3.tm_min` to get the minutes field:

```
if epg_time_3.tm_min == 30:
    print "you are here, now let do something..."
```